# How to set proxy on agsXMPP

Tags: facebook, xmpp, agsxmpp

i am new on agsXMPP i connected to the facebook and now able to make chat on the facebook but i have now one problem i am unable to make login on the proxy server like i have a serve which use proxy 168.10.10.19 and port 8080 so i am using this proxy to connect to the net so my program is not able to being log in so what i can do to make my program to work on proxy server now what i am doing is this

```
    Jid jidUser = new Jid("UserName");

    xmppCon.Username = jidUser.User;
    xmppCon.Server = "chat.facebook.com";
    xmppCon.Password = "Password";
    xmppCon.AutoResolveConnectServer = true;

    xmppCon.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

port 8080 looks to me like you are using a HTTP proxy.
When you are using a HTTP proxy then you cannot connect directly to Facebook because they don't run a BOSH connection manager. You can only connect over TCP/IP sockets.

The only way would be running your own BOSH Server which proxies all your Facebook XMPP traffic to the Facebook XMPP servers over HTTP. Then you can use BOSH in agsXMPP and set your internal company proxy there.

If you HTTP proxy allows HTTP CONNECT its easier. But I have not seen many proxies in the wild which allow HTTP connect.

Comment: thanks bro for the reply but can you give me the link or code or any thing that show how to connect chat.facebook.com using agsXMPP on http proxy server if i want to open the site i set the proxy in browsers so i can use the internet or make to open the site so how can i set the proxy in agsXMPP to connect to the internet